# Is this how you go about calling your Dao's in your service layer?

Tags: java, oop

In your service layer, say you have a method that does XX, is this how you would reference your Dao classes?

```
public class SomeServiceImpl implements SomeService

    public void DoSomething(int someThingId){

    UserDao userDao = this.daoFactory().GetUserDao();
    SalesDao salesDao = this.daoFactory().GetSalesDao();
    ..
    ..
    ..

    }
```

It gets a bit much to do this, and was hoping if there was a easier more elegant way?

Comment: This is exactly how I would do it without a DI container! However if you make use of some sort of DI container e.g. Spring then it could be simplified to what @Ralph has said but other than that what you have is perfectly fine IMHO. But DI if your not familiar with it would be worthwhile looking into, keeps things more loosely coupled.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use Springframework to configure my application. This framework has the nice feature that enables me to Inject the dependencies into my service layer. Therefore the Service implementation looks something like that:

```
@Autowired
private UserDAO userDao;
public void doSomething(int someThingId) {
userDAO.findById(someThingId);
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how "Proper" it is but I often make private getters for the DAO objects (properties) and make them lazy loading. Makes it less verbose. You then can create a base service class if particular Dao are used in several places...

```
public class SomeServiceImpl implements SomeService
{
    private UserDao _UserDao

    private UserDao getUserDao()
    {
        if (_UserDao == null)
        {
            _UserDao = DaoFactory.GetUserDao();
        }

        return _UserDao;
    }

    public void DoSomething(int somethingId)
    {
        this.getUserDao().findById(somethingId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either use annotation or xml configuration to inject dao dependency at run time.